# format Python output

Tags: python, templates

I'm using `template.format()` to have two columns aligned, like this

```
a    1
b    3
c    6
```

I tried the following:

```
template = "{0:30}{2:7}"
w.write("| "+(template.format("a",len(a.findall(info)))+"\n"))
w.write("| "+template.format("b",count)+"\n")
```

I had this

```
a   1
b 5
```

it is not aligned 
why did this happen? any one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your template is wrong. Please have a look at this:

```
template = "{:30}{:7}"
print(template.format("agasdf","1"))
print(template.format("b","ddsfg5ggg"))
print(template.format("hgfdhb","5ggg"))
```

Gives nice formatting in columns:

```
agasdf                        1      
b                             ddsfg5ggg
hgfdhb                        5ggg
```